# SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level for systemml

Tags: python, keras, import

I'm trying to import the `Keras2DML` class from the `systemml` library but keep getting this syntax error. Anyone know how to fix it? I'm not inside a function when calling this import.
Current COde:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from keras.layers import Dropout, LSTM, Dense, Input, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

from systemml.mllearn import *

class TrainLSTMModel:

    def __init__(self,  csv_file = None, column_number = None, timesteps = 30 ):
        self.csv_file = csv_file
        self.column_number = column_number
        self.timesteps = timesteps
        self.train_LSTM_model()


    def train_LSTM_model(self):
        '''This method will return a trained LSTM model based on the csv_file based in for training'''
        # Spark Session
        #conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Spark DL Pipeline').setMaster('local[8]')
        #sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

        dataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csv_file)
        # Grab the desired column of the training data
        train_data = dataframe.iloc[:,self.column_number].values 
        # Reshaping to a 2D array
        train_data = train_data.reshape(-1,1)
        print(train_data.dtype)
        print(type(train_data))
        print(train_data.shape) 

        # Feature Scaling
        sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        scaled_train_data =sc.fit_transform(train_data)

        # Initialzing each x_train and y_train datasets for each column
        X_train = []
        y_train = []

        # Appending scaled training data to each dataset
        for i in range(self.timesteps, len(train_data)):
            X_train.append(scaled_train_data[i - self.timesteps:i, 0])
            y_train.append(scaled_train_data[i, 0])

        # Numpy array creation, Keras requires numpy arrays for Inputs
        X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train, dtype=int), np.array(y_train)
        print(X_train.shape)
        print(X_train.dtype)

        # Reshaping to a 3D matrix (970, 30, 1)
        #X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train[0], X_train[1], 1))
        print(X_train.shape)


        # Reshapes to input neuron
        input_train_model = Input(shape =  (X_train.shape[1], 1), name='input_train_model')

        #Training Layers
        x_1 = LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1))(input_train_model)
        x_1 = Dropout(0.2)(x_1)
        x_1 = LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True)(x_1)
        x_1 = Dropout(0.2)(x_1)
        x_1 = LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True)(x_1)
        x_1 = Dropout(0.2)(x_1)
        x_1 = LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True)(x_1)
        x_1 = Dropout(0.2)(x_1)
        x_1 = Flatten()(x_1)

        # 1 ouptut neuron for each column prediction
        output_train_data = Dense(units=1, name= 'ouput_train_data')(x_1)
        model = Model(inputs=input_train_model, outputs=output_train_data)
        model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

        epochs = 5
        batch_size = 100
        samples = 60000
        max_iter = int(epochs*math.ceil(samples/batch_size))
        sysml_model = Keras2DML(spark, keras_model, input_shape=(1,28,28), weights='weights_dir', batch_size=batch_size, max_iter=max_iter, test_interval=0, display=10)
        #return model
```

Error in Jupyter Notebooks:

```
File "/Users/vnovelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-58-2e205cfea32b>", line 12, in <module>
    from systemml.mllearn import Keras2DML

  File "/Users/vnovelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/systemml/mllearn/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .estimators import *



    File "/Users/vnovelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/systemml/mllearn/estimators.py", line 917
    def __init__(self, sparkSession, keras_model, input_shape, transferUsingDF=False, load_keras_weights=True, weights=None, labels=None, batch_size=64, max_iter=2000, test_iter=10, test_interval=500, display=100, lr_policy="step", weight_decay=5e-4, regularization_type="L2"):
    ^
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level`
```

Output in VSCode:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats_app_systemml.py", line 10, in <module>
    from systemml.mllearn import *
  File "/Users/vnovelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/systemml/mllearn/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .estimators import *
  File "/Users/vnovelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/systemml/mllearn/estimators.py", line 917
    def __init__(self, sparkSession, keras_model, input_shape, transferUsingDF=False, load_keras_weights=True, weights=None, labels=None, batch_size=64, max_iter=2000, test_iter=10, test_interval=500, display=100, lr_policy="step", weight_decay=5e-4, regularization_type="L2"):
    ^
SyntaxError
```

Comment: What's the exact code that you're running, and are you using jupyter? This looks kind of like jupyter is wrapping whatever you're doing in an `exec` call.

Comment: Yes im using Jupyter notebooks but even VSCode im gettinjg this error @HansMusgrave

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from keras.layers import Dropout, LSTM, Dense, Input, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

from systemml.mllearn import *
` @HansMusgrave this is literally all the code...

Comment: Please add that to your question, and also, what's the error message you get in VSCode?

Comment: Check my new upadted question @HansMusgrave

Comment: @codemonkey sorry I have posted this on the wrong question lol my bad mate

Comment: The two bugs look unrelated. The first looks like an artifact of how jupyter is calling your code. The second looks like a bug in systemml (but as I'm looking through the source I'm having trouble finding it, and it seems odd that such a core component would have a syntax error).

Comment: @HansMusgrave if yo go to the documentation of systemml in the repo systemml/src/main/python/systemml/mllearn it runs the __init__.py which then imports all the classes in the __all__ from the estimators.py file. Link to repo:https://github.com/apache/systemml/tree/master/src/main/python/systemml/mllearn

Comment: Yep, I was also suspecting of these `__all__` assignations. By the way, your stacktrace shows the error at `line 917`, while last version have the `__init__` method at line 1030 (https://github.com/apache/systemml/blob/master/src/main/python/systemml/mllearn/estimators.py#L1030). Could you upgrade, please? (just to discard that)

Comment: @HansMusgrave would that be just `pip install --upgrade sytemml`? Im trying to upgrade the package but still getting the error on line 917. Thanks for helping me out btw :)

Comment: @HansMusgrave ^^

Comment: FYI it was slackmart who recommended an upgrade. Anyway, it looks like you're using anaconda, so `pip install systemml --upgrade` should work. You can probably also use the `conda` CLI if desired. Are you getting an error on line 917 while upgrading?

Comment: @HansMusgrave oh my bad. I tried installing with pip and i still get the same error on line 917. When I try to install with `conda install systemml`, it says the package can't be found...not sure what to do at this point :(

Comment: @slackmart could you check my previous comment? ^^